# WITH clause with function returning VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write a SQL query using function in WITH clause.

`

```
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    l_pid VARCHAR2(38);
  BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CHAR(p_id) INTO l_pid FROM dual;
    RETURN l_pid;
  END;
SELECT with_function(2.23327463784638764)
FROM   DUAL;
```

`

Length of the value passed to `with_function` can vary. Hence `l_pid VARCHAR2(38);` would not work when length of `p_id` is greater than 38. I can give maximum length (32767) to `p_id` while declaring it or i can use a procedure with out parameter but i would like to know if there is any other way to not hardcode the length when using function in WITH clause.

Comment: What about replacing `VARCHAR2(38)` with `CLOB` ..?

Comment: What does this function give you over just using the Oracle built-in `to_char()` ? Beyond that, Oracle has hard limits on the number of digits which can be expressed as a NUMBER datatype and the length of a string which can be used in SQL (unless you've switched on the extended length semantics), so what is the deal here?

Comment: Your function's body can be simplified to `return to_char(p_id);` then you also don't need the variable any more (but then the question: what is that function for)

Comment: If either answer solved your issue please accept it. That helps future questioners with the same issue. Accepting also removes it from  Active (unanswered) queue.  If neither  resolve your issue, what remains to be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to create a variable to assign result of `to_char`. Just return the result directly.

```
with 
  function with_function(p_id in number) 
    return varchar2 is
  begin
    return to_char(p_id);
  end;
select with_function(2.23327463784638764)
from   dual;
```

-- 2.23327463784638764

Answer (score 1):

A [`NUMBER` only stores up to a precision of 38 digits](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020):

> `NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]`
>
> Number having precision `p` and scale `s`. The precision `p` can range from 1 to 38. The scale `s` can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and scale are in decimal digits. A `NUMBER` value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

Therefore, the maximum length you need is 40 characters (with a decimal point and negative sign) as any precision greater than that is going to be lost when storing it as a `NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH
  FUNCTION with_function(p_id IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    l_pid VARCHAR2(40);
  BEGIN
    SELECT TO_CHAR(p_id) INTO l_pid FROM dual;
    RETURN l_pid;
  END;
data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT 1234567898012345678980123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1234567898012345678980.123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 0.1234567898012345678980123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -1234567898012345678980123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -1234567898012345678980.123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT -0.1234567898012345678980123456789801234567898012345678980 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT with_function(value)
FROM   data;
```

Outputs:

> | WITH_FUNCTION(VALUE) |
> | --- |
> | 1.2345678980123456789801234567898012E+54 |
> | 1234567898012345678980.12345678980123457 |
> | .123456789801234567898012345678980123457 |
> | -1.234567898012345678980123456789801E+54 |
> | -1234567898012345678980.1234567898012346 |
> | -.12345678980123456789801234567898012346 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a160bf2c18183d5d77e183080b1e277)*